# How to update multiple entities in Cuba Platform Frontend UI

Tags: cuba-platform

I have a function that returns data from many entities and puts them in a table. When the table is changed and the save button is clicked I need to send all the data to their entities. Is there a way to do this in one action?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need a REST API method which can update several entities at once - then there is no such built-in method in the CUBA REST addon.
However, backend developers can create and expose a "service method" for you that accepts list of entities or POJOs as parameter. Then you will be able to call it from the web page.

See https://doc.cuba-platform.com/restapi-7.2/#rest_api_v2_ex_service_post